# loading large data in the SlickGrid

Tags: performance, large-data, slickgrid

I am using SlickGrid ([GitHub](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid)) in my electron application and I need to handle the (load/browse/edit) a large dataset (say: 10 millions rows and 1000 columns). I tried using DataView, but the DataView expects the whole data in a JavaScript array at once. Loading the large data in the JS array is very slow. How can I achieve fast loading and fast scrolling using SlickGrid?

Comment: loading that much data and that many columns without using backend pagination will be problematic. Personally when I deal with few thousand rows, I use backend pagination, I've done 2 backend services (OData or GraphQL) using the DataView and I had to build my own Pagination component and it works fine, I'm overwriting the data every time I change page, see [Angular-Slickgrid with OData](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/odata) demo. only downside is that you cannot use features like Grouping because you don't have all the data on hand apart from that it's super quick

Comment: @ghiscoding you have a valid point. Since my electron app is not built on any framework like Angular, can I still use OData?
Another way I was thinking of is pulling a small set of data (say 100 rows) and populate the JS array and then refresh the DataView. Based on the scroll direction I can repopulate the JS array and the DataView with another set of data. But then I can do this without DataView also. Not sure which one is the best. DataView features like Sorting, Grouping are of no use if I load partial data.

Comment: The OData was a Service built for my lib, however you can take a look at another lib I have created recently [Slickgrid-Universal](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal) it has the OData and it is framework agnostic, all the demos are with plain TypeScript (it works with ES6 syntax too). For the DataView portion, the Sorting should be handled by your backend query (like OData) and the Grouping is the only thing you're out of (it Groups only on current page). The other thing I've done in another project is to load 500 rows first so the user can work and then push portion bit by bit

Comment: ... so you load data in multiple pass, this allows your user interact with some data while you're pushing more data in the background and even when you use Grouping, it keeps the group and just indirectly add more data to the group. This remove the jaggering and works quite well but you'll still have the slowness on the Sorting/Grouping/Filtering/etc... it's not ideal to work with over a million data, it works but it's not the best

Comment: FYI, look at https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples, there are two AJAX-loading examples that cover pulling data from a web API. Note that they are both broken, due to changes in or disappearance of the API over time, but they did work once upon a time!

Comment: @ghiscoding I will come back to [Slickgrid-Universal](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal) if I could not find any easier solution. This appears to be very advanced and bit complex for me. Right now, I am looking for something native to slickgrid.

Comment: @BenMcIntyre I guess AJAX loading examples may provide me what I need. I will check those examples as I am already looking into the Slickgrid API docs and examples.

Comment: note people have used the grid with *a lot* of rows: https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/pull/374